# Normality of some generic ultrafilter

Tags: set-theory, forcing, large-cardinals

My question is about some proof details in Lemma 6.4 in Gitik's chapter from the Handbook of Set Theory.

On the sequel suppose that,

- $j:V\longrightarrow M$ stands for the elementary embedding derived from a normal measure $U$ over $\kappa$ in $V$.
- $\mathbb{P}_\kappa$ is a Magidor iteration of Prikry type forcings with the following property:
  $$\text{$\forall\alpha<\kappa\;\forall p,q,r\in\mathbb{Q}_\alpha\; (p,q\leq^*_\alpha r\;\longrightarrow \;\exists s\in\mathbb{Q}_\alpha\;( s\leq^*_\alpha p,q))$}.$$
  (For instance, any Magidor iteration of Prikry forcings enjoy this property.)
- If $\mathbb{P}_{j(\kappa)}$ is the image by $j$ of the iteration, the forcing $(\mathbb{P}_{j(\kappa)}\setminus\kappa,\leq^*)$ is $\kappa^+$-closed.

Now define the following ultrafilter over $\kappa$ in the generic extension $V[G]$:

$$X\in U^*\;\longleftrightarrow\; \exists p\in G\cap M\,\exists q\leq^* j(p)\setminus\kappa\; (p\frown q\Vdash_{j(\mathbb{P}_\kappa)} \kappa\in j(\dot{X})). $$

What I would like to know is the proof that this ultrafilter $U^*$ is also normal. Gitik gives some indications but I am not able to manage a proof. Any help will be wellcome.

Comment: Wait, $G\in M$? I thought that $G$ is the generic filter defining $V[G]$. If $G\in M$, then $G\in V$ so $V[G]=V$...

Comment: Sorry, it's a typo. What I would like to say is $p\in G\cap M$.

Comment: Okay. I'm not entirely sure what is the Magidor iteration of Prikry forcings (is it just the Magidor forcing? to change the cofinality of $\kappa$ to be countable by adding a club of points where you changed the cofinalities?) But in the usual case, $\Bbb P_\kappa$ would actually be a subset of $M$ (since its elements are in $M$ and $M$ is closed under $\kappa$-sequences). So $G\subseteq M$ as well. Or what exactly is meant by the Magidor iteration of Prikry forcings? (I ask since I don't have the book in front of me right now...)

Comment: Yes, in practice you can simply consider Magidor forcing. I guess that the book refers to that forcing as Magidor iterations and not as Magidor forcing because the Magidor forcing is a Magidor iteration where the iterates are the corresponding Prikry forcings.

Comment: In lemma 6.4 the measure U, is a normal (fine) measure on $\mathcal{P}_{\kappa}(\lambda)$ which witness that $\kappa$ is $\lambda$-strong compact. Later it is said ''if $U$ is normal and $\langle \mathbb{P}_{j(\kappa)}\setminus \kappa \ | \ \leq^{*} \rangle $ is $\lambda^{+}$-closed, then it follows that $U^{*}$ is normal'' (maybe you want to add this in the question).   I'd try to use exercise 22.6 of Kanamori's book.